Override Wordpress focus outline
Form elements in wordpress have a black outline, added by this rule:
:where(.wp-site-blocks :focus) {
  outline-width: 2px;
  outline-style: solid;
}

I want to override it and remove it, I tried different rules (added to the style.css of the child theme):
 .wp-site-blocks :focus {
    outline-width: 0 !important;
    outline-style: none !important;
  }

.wp-site-blocks *:focus {
  outline-width: 0 !important;
  outline-style: none !important;
}

But no rule is taking effect.

Why are you working with completely different selectors, why are you not using the same one? As long as your custom CSS gets embedded after the default one, that should already work.

@C3roe I already tried the same selector but it does not work.

So what formatting do you see apply, when inspecting one of the elements in question? Does what you tried to add show at all? Is it crossed out, because it gets overwritten by the original code?

@C3roe my rule does not shows in the inspector, other my custom rules do. It's not greyed out or overwritten. It's just not there regardless of the selected element. (In the inspector I have also enabled :focus and :focus-visible).

Sounds like your modifications somehow not "took" correctly to begin with, because you should be able to see both, even if only one applies.

Could you describe exactly how you are including your CSS? And when you say that wordpress give a black outline, is that actually from whatever theme you are using? What theme are you using?

The selectors you have used bear no direct relationship to the one which begins ':where - that one selects elements with class wp-site-blocks and elements with :focus. Your selectors require the focused item to be a descendant of an element with class wp-site-blocks.
